# How to sort order in Django Related Models (Generic relations)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My models:

**HitCounter:**

```
hits  = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
object_pk  = models.TextField('object ID')
content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                        verbose_name="content cype",
                        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",)
content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')
```

**Item:**

```
title    = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=400)
desc     = models.TextField(_('Description'), blank=True
```

)

I want to sort order the items in Item by hits in HitCounter? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
items = Item.objects.annotate(hits=Sum('hitcounter__hits')).order_by('-hits')
```

Doc for Django aggregation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Is your first model named 'HitCounter' and you're still getting an exception? Can you post the message?

Comment: I have took an ordered list of the id of the Item. But how to get the items from Item object with it. I have used for loop but looks not good.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I have made a question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364905/django-sort-order-the-list-in-objects. Please visit and take your points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the meta options [`order_with_respect_to`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) and [`ordering`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#ordering) help, if you want to have this ordering by default.

Your model would look like this then:

```
class HitCounter:
    # properties here

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to: 'content_object'  # not sure if this really works
        ordering: ['-hits']
```

Comment: django.db.models.fields.FieldDoesNotExist: HitCounter (or whatever) has no field named 'content_object'