# Django: Sort order the list in objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have `list1` in order by id. Like this:

```
['4','2','1','17'] #edited
```

How to get `list2` from object Entry in order of `list1`.

In the case Query ValueList, as well as on the question.

```
[u'4', u'2', u'1', u'17']
```

Because some properties are not in QuerySet

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Is `list1` in a random order or is there some pattern? Because in your example, the IDs are sorted in descending order.

Comment: list1 is in random order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can use `in_bulk()` and then just get dict values in defined order. Wrap this in custom manager for further comfort

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... END` in order to sort your IDs. Pass the full `CASE` clause in the `select` argument of [`extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none), and the use the `order_by` argument with the given field name.